# collectd write_http plugin failure

Tags: metrics, collectd, observability

I am trying to get our collectd server to forward metrics via the write_http plugin. It seems to be failing with its use of curl. I have done a tcpdump listening for port 80tcp traffic and it isn't even trying to connect to the http server. Below is the error from the. Ollectd.log and the. Ollectd.conf I am using. Hoping someone here can suggest a solution or some additional debug steps. Thanks.

2024-03-13 16:15:02] [error] write_http plugin: curl_easy_perform failed with status 7:

LoadPlugin syslog

LoadPlugin cpu

LoadPlugin interface

LoadPlugin load

LoadPlugin memory

LoadPlugin logfile

```
    LogLevel info

    File "/var/log/collectd.log"

    Timestamp true

    PrintSeverity true
```

```
 ReportNumCpu true
```

LoadPlugin write_http

```
     <Node "gitmetrics">

       URL http://<obfuscated>/metricspost

       Format "JSON"

       Header "Content-Type: application/json"

       Metrics true

       VerifyPeer false

       VerifyHost false

       StoreRates true

       Timeout 5000

       LogHttpError true

     </Node>
```

LoadPlugin network

```
<Listen "0.0.0.0" "25826">

</Listen>
```

Include "/etc/collectd.d"

Tried various http servers including one on local host to rule out network/firewall issues. Expectation is the metrics flowing to collectd should be forwarded to our http endpoint.